# Jenkins PermGen errors despite higher setting

Tags: java, jenkins

I am running a fairly new jenkins install on ubuntu 13.10 and I can't seem to get the thing to stay up more than a couple hours before I start getting memory errors like the following:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I have installed the monitor plugin and it claims there is only 82m available in the permgen.
[image]
I have edited /etc/environment on my jenkins server to include the following lines:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms768m -Xmx1024m"
JAVA_ARGS="-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

I am pretty sure that the args are getting picked up because my timezone seems correct now.  I am running java 1.7.

Comment: Your /etc/environment might not be picked up by Jenkins. What Linux OS is it? Look for the jenkins daemon file (/etc/init.d/jenkins) and see how it builds the java command. See output of 'ps -ef | grep jenkins'. Check the memory parameters there.

Comment: After reading the /etc/init.d/jenkins file as Eldad suggested I found that on ubuntu jenkins reads in the JAVA_ARGS from /etc/defaults/jenkins.  Making my edits there solved my issue.

Comment: I'll post an official answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **/etc/environment** might not be picked up by Jenkins. What Linux OS is it? Look for the jenkins daemon file (**/etc/init.d/jenkins**) and see how it builds the java command.

See output of `ps -ef | grep jenkins`. Check the actual memory parameters used by Java there.